# How to bring background android app which monitors light sensor to foreground

Tags: android, background, sensors, foreground

I just started android programming.
So far I got an app working which starts monitoring the light sensor in onResume and stops
monitoring in onDestroy (intentionally not in onPause) because if the Phone goes into sleep
after some nonactivity i want to keep monitoring the light sensor to be able to react if
the Phone is in a dark place. If it is I want to implement some functionality with UI.
What is the correct way to implement this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

onDestroy() is not a good place to have any core logic because it is not guaranteed to be called. Only when the OS feels that it needs more memory, this callback may be issued.

A good way to do it would be to start a service on application launch that does the monitoring. You could make it sticky (or not) depending on the kind of functionality you need. You could use a broadcast to communicate this to your activity. This way, you keep the sensor part decoupled from the UI.

If you don't intend to do that, this might help you 
[android light sensor - detect significant light changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411562/android-light-sensor-detect-significant-light-changes)

Comment: Okay thanks, but will my activity to be able to show op again after receiving the broadcast with the screen off and locked?

Comment: Maybe it is good to mention that I want only to be processing if the application is active. So if the user decides to leave the app all processing can stop, my only concern is the sleep/lock screen. Perhaps I should use a Wakelock instead?