# Find light on camera

Tags: java, android, camera, flashlight

Is it possible to check if there is flashlight turned on on another device with camera( find strong light) ? I didn't find any interesting things on internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Android  [light sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411562/android-light-sensor-detect-significant-light-changes).

OR
[OpenCV](https://opencv.org/platforms/android/) .